# After updating React-Native to 0.59.2 it fails to run

Tags: android, react-native, indexing, upgrade

After I did this update of react native my app fails to run. It shows error code 500 on my screen. Erro: unable to resolve module index from ./node_modules/react-native/scripts

I tried deleting node-modules and reinstalling them. I reset cache, I cleaned project on android studio, build it. Nothing works!

Any suggestions?!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this ?

```sh
react-native upgrade
```

Or for a specific version you can try this ...

```sh
react-native upgrade 0.59.2
```

You can check the docs [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/upgrading)

Comment: the only workaround is by running metro bundle using --reset--cache command and on a separate cmd run android. But I dont want to keep running it like that.

Answer (score 0):

For now I just downgraded to the previous version, it works fine.